# Modernizr flickers my page and seems to add trouble when loading jQuery

Tags: jquery, stylesheet, modernizr

**Edit:** I need to revise my question to better cover my problem. I have two problems I need to adress:

1. The page loads in chunks as it renders the pages each building blocks on the screen.
2. My different jQuery-functions seem to execute differently.

This is my modernizr call:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Javascript/modernizr.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    Modernizr.load([
        {
            load: [
                'App_Themes/Computer/General.css',
                'App_Themes/Computer/Scaling.css',
                'App_Themes/Computer/jquery.fullPage.css'
            ],
            complete: function () {
                Modernizr.load([
                    {
                        //CDN reference provided by http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-javascript-fallback-methods/ | Jake Rocheleau
                        load: 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js',
                        complete: function () {
                            if (!window.jQuery) {
                                Modernizr.load('JavaScript/jquery-1.11.1.min.js');
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        load: 'JavaScript/jquery.queryloader2.js'
                    },
                    {
                        load: [
                            'JavaScript/jquery.easings.min.js',
                            'JavaScript/jquery.slimscroll.min.js',
                            'JavaScript/jquery.fullpage.min.js'
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        load: 'JavaScript/jquery-functions.js'
                    }
                ]);
            }
        }
    ]);
</script>
```

The reason I load things with different load-wings is that I want to ensure that certain scripts are loaded before the next set of scripts load.

Now - how do I remove this kind of 'loading-my-page-in-chunks'? I believe it has something to do with executing the scripts before it has finished loading the styles, but I don't understand why based on the order I'm calling things.

Second - how can I check if the jQuery is loaded? I have a div inside the fullpage afterRender that's supposed to fade out after 4 seconds but it never triggers... (The commented callback produced absolutely nothing while uncommented). If I place the document.ready inline I get the error that $ is not defined which signals me that the jQuery never even loads before the fullPage-function executes fully...

Could someone please point me in some direction?

Comment: Move your scripts to the bottom right before `</body>`. The flickering usually occurs if you are setting positions or dimensions via javascript to your html elements.

Comment: That seems fair. I'll have a look at it when I leave work and get back to you.

Comment: Can you please reproduce the issue on http://jsbin.com ? Don't forget to write a follow-up comment so that we can notice the change.

Comment: Sure thing. I'll do it this evening (Swedish time) ;)

Comment: @Patsy Issa - I'm sorry to report that moving the scripts to right above the '</body>'-tag didn't do the trick at all. The site still loads in chunks. :( please take a look at this [link](http://www.gisslen.net).

Comment: Move all your scripts not just the modernizer one

Comment: All scripts are loaded within the 'Modernizr.load'-function. No scripts are loaded outside it. :/